# Pyserial and tkinter not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, logic, pyserial

I'm currently working on a project that requires serial communication and a GUI. I'm new to python so i'm really stuck, could not find any information about this so i guess that it's a logical problem but i can't figure it out. Any subject help is greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import serial, time, os

codeRead = open ('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/acticode.taws', 'r')
code = codeRead.read()
codeRead.close()

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:
    serialInput = ser.readline()

    if serialInput == b'1001\r\n':      #Read Input 1001
        file1 = open('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I1.taws', 'w')
        file1.write(code)
        file1.close()

    if serialInput == b'1002\r\n':      #Read Input 1002
        if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I1.taws'):
            os.remove('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I1.taws')

    if serialInput == b'2001\r\n':      #Read Input 2001
        file2 = open('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I2.taws', 'w')
        file2.write(code)
        file2.close()

    if serialInput == b'2002\r\n':      #Read Input 2002
        if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I2.taws'):
            os.remove('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I2.taws')

    if serialInput == b'3001\r\n':      #Read Input 3001
        file3 = open('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I3.taws', 'w')
        file3.write(code);
        file3.close()

    if serialInput == b'3002\r\n':      #Read Input 3002
        if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I3.taws'):
            os.remove('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I3.taws')

    if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I1.taws'):        #Write Pin 10
        ser.write(b'1')

    if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I2.taws'):        #Write Pin 8
        ser.write(b'2')

    if os.path.isfile('/home/riverans/Desktop/com/I3.taws'):
        ser.write(b'3')

    print (serialInput)


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("MISSYS")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label='Undo')
        menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit)


        button1 = Button(self, text="Turn on LED", command=self.serial_write_led)
        button1.place(x=0, y=0)

        button2 = Button(self, text="Turn off LED", command=self.serial_write_led2)
        button2.place(x=100, y=0)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def serial_write_led(self):
        ser.write(b'1')
        print("Turning on LED")

    def serial_write_led2(self):
        ser.write(b'2')
        print("Turning off LED")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd like to think that the indendation I just corrected in your `class Window` was due to bad copy-pasting. I would suggest specifying **why** this doesn't work; you can't simply paste the code and expect other users to magically discover the errors.

Comment: Can you point out **what exactly** the problem with your code is?

Comment: @DimitrisJim The indentation is not right.  Look at the `while` loop at the beginning.

Comment: Missed that, fixed it up now.

Comment: You have an infinite loop at the beginning of your code.  You'll never get to the point where you create the Tk object.  I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly, so I can't suggest how to correct it.

Comment: More that having an endless loop, you seem to have two parts of main routines. I personally prefer having definition section and calling sections in code files. So to say "Main Routine / Calls at end of file", and "class and function definitions / declaration" at the beginning.

As you have a mainloop you do not need a endless loop elsewhere. The mainloop will run as long as your application lasts.
You could use tkinters `Entry-Widget` as an input for your so-called `serial console`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
NEVER use Infinite loop or `time.sleep(ms)` when working with Tkinter GUI because when you write the last line `top.mainloop()` , tkinter creates its own loop to keep the application live until you close it manually. And your Loop or the sleep function will interfere with tkinter's mainloop

Next thing - I found out that if you are using `pyserial` module with tkinter, this also causes problem. It is because when you are reading from the serial port, it is making python wait till there is something in the serial buffer to read. So, I guess internally somewhere there is a loop for this.

Now, How I managed to solve my problem -
I created two python scripts. One that fetches data from serial port, and another that displays the GUI. Then, I am running both the scripts separately but together. First script fetches data from serial port and dumps in a file and the GUI script reads the same file. And thus I managed to get the serial data on GUI.

It is not a very good way, but my purpose is solved.